# Elasticsearch filter only if no matches to first filter

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

My use case is for searching UK addresses where there is a well defined postal code system however my users may still make mistakes in the postcode.  I want to use a filter as in most cases the user will get the postcode right and I do not want to make Elasticsearch work harder than it needs to however I want to avoid roundtrips from my application to ES.

I am using an `edge n-gram` analyzer as described in the docs, so, taking the postcode `ME4 4NR` as an example I have `ME4 4NR`, `ME4 4N`, `ME4 4` and `ME4` indexed.  I want to first filter by `ME4 4NR` and only widen to `ME4 4N` if this yields no matches.

Can I achieve this in my ES query or do I need to implement this in my application logic?  Any advice would be much appreciated.  I could use a boolean filter with a `must` on the `ME4` and `should`s on the others but I wondered if there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are a bit over-complicating the matter here. This if-this-then-that-else-somethingelse can be achieved with ES, but the cases when this is possible are limited. For example - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652019/elastic-search-general-and-conditional-filters/30654826#30654826) - the "else" part was a `must` in which the statement was a `bool` filter that first checked another `must` with a `missing` "condition". So, something must still be true in order for the other part of a "if-then-else" statement to be applied. Is not a strict matter of doing this only if "a certain condition" is true or false like in programming. You need to approach this Elasticsearch way, not programming way.

Your solution - use a `must` on `ME4` and `should`s on the others - is not necessary imo. If you have `analyzer` set to an edge n-gram, then the same analyzer is used at indexing time but also **at search** time. Which means that, depending on the query/filter used, your input text **will be analyzed** before the search is performed.

For example, if you use at search time `match` query, then the input text you provide is analyzed. What this means is that if you input `ME4 4N` as search text, first ES will edge n-gram the input text and use the resulting tokens to search the inverted index. So, no need of doing this in your own code or come up with multiple `should`s in your ES query.

My suggestion here is to have a well-defined set of requirements set up properly first. Meaning, know what you want your search to do: think about the tokens that should be put in the inverted index and think about what users input. Decide if you need analysis at index time, **but also at search time**. Depending on this, think about the ways to use filters/queries at search time, meaning which analyze the input text and which don't (`term` doesn't for example while `match` does). **Then, test you approaches and see the performance.** Don't assume something is putting more work on ES than it should because you might be wrong. Test and compare the results, then start improving and coming up with other ideas.

Comment: Thank your for your advice Andrei, much appreciated.  I now have a filter on the first part (e.g. ME4) where supplied which makes life a lot easier for ES on 70 million records and keeps the search performing well and the results sensible and then pass the full postcode to the analyzer as a regular match query and let it do its thing, results are great so far, thanks again for your help.